# Mysql delete by difference in time()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete every row where the time difference is 5 minutes. I'm using time() as an int.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE time()-time > 300");
```

the query is the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`time()`**](http://www.php.net/time) is a PHP function -- and has absolutely no meaning in SQL.

You should either :

- use one of MySQL's [datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

  - To get an UNIX Timestamp, I suppose `unix_timestamp(now())` might do the trick.
- or get `time()` out of the SQL query, so it's evaluated by PHP.

For example, using the second idea, I suppose you could do something like this :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE " . time() . "-time > 300");
```

Comment: Please NEVER use string concatenation in real SQL queries - this can lead to SQL injection. ALWAYS use SQL parameters binding. Unfortunately in PHP the only choice is use `mysql_real_escape_string` and string concatenation. :-(

Comment: In many situations, I would agree with you ; but when doing this *(only using the result of a know PHP function)*, there is not much risk of SQL Injection, really. And if working with integers, no need to escape like a string : use intval() ;;; and there are prepared statements, using either MySQLi or PDO *(mysql is the old extension, that shouldn't be used for new projects)*

Comment: Of course in this situation it's OK to use string concatenation with not escaped time() result. Only wanted to add my comment about more generic case for people which will look at your answer in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the time is a column in the users table, this is what you need:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE NOW() - INTERVAL 300 SECOND > time");
```

NOW() is a function that brings back the time on the DB server rather than the web server.

Just make sure the clocks on the DB server and Web server are sync'd

Here is a sample using SELECT

```
mysql> select now(),(now() - INTERVAL 300 SECOND);
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| now()               | (now() - INTERVAL 300 SECOND) |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2011-04-15 16:21:41 | 2011-04-15 16:16:41           |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can format code blocks by highlighting them and hitting Ctrl-K, or clicking the `{}` button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE time < '".(time()-300)."' ");
and this query will be cached by mysql