# Select fields from next row in subquery based on time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to grab a field from the next row then calculate the timedifference between field of current row and field of next row in Mysql. but it always give me a very large timediff of 60hours. Since this is more than a day, it have to be wrong.

MY Query goes like this:

```
select DATE_FORMAT( last_call, '%d' ) AS 'day',
    COUNT(call_id) as id,

   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM((select timestampdiff(second, calls.last_call, c2.last_call)
    from calls c2
    where c2.calling_agent = calls.calling_agent and
          c2.last_call > calls.last_call and
          timestampdiff(second, calls.last_call, c2.last_call) > 600
    order by c2.last_call
    limit 1
   ))) brakes
```

from calls
WHERE calling_agent =9
 AND last_call > DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
GROUP BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM last_call )

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/5681925/1693947](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5681925/1693947) might be helpful

Comment: Define 'next row'. And identify which RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the next value using a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select c2.last_call
        from calls c2
        where c2.calling_agent = c.calling_agent and
              c2.last_call > c.last_call
        order by c2.last_call
        limit 1
       ) next_last_call
from calls c;
```

You can use `timestampdiff()` to get the difference between the next and the current, if you like:

```
select c.*,
       (select timestampdiff(second, c.last_call, c2.last_call)
        from calls c2
        where c2.calling_agent = c.calling_agent and
              c2.last_call > c.last_call
        order by c2.last_call
        limit 1
       ) diff_in_secs
from calls c;
```

And then apply whatever logic you want (perhaps using this as a subquery).

Comment: i dont understand how to add this to my query so that it gets me the timediff between each row for every day? But only the ones that are greather than 10 min? can you please help???